# Как получить длину текста в EditText (inputType=number) c учётом нулей?

Tags: android, android-edittext

Всем привет! Рассматриваемый EditText - для ввода ИНН, поэтому inputType=number. Понятно, что нужно проверять количество введённых символов (в данном случае - цифр).

Проверяю через editText.getText().toString().length() - других способов, честно,  не знаю.

Но тут застала маленькая засада - ИНН может включать в себя 0 (нули), которые  .length() не учитывает при подсчёте количества символов.

Как же определить количество символов с учётом этих нулей? Гугл не помог.

Comment: Ваша проблема заключается определенно в чем-то еще, потому что метод length() у класса String учитывает любые символы, в том числе '0'. Проверьте сначала, действительно ли Вы получаете ту строку, которую ожидаете.

Comment: Строку из EditText беру в нужном месте в нужный момент. Перепроверял много раз и по-разному. При вводе без нулей всё работает как надо.

Comment: Думаю, пикантность ситуации придает атрибут inputType=number. Из-за него на стадии getText нули могут отбрасываться. Это предположение.

Comment: Выведите строку в лог и убедитесь, что объект String состоит из тех же символов, что Вы ввели.

Comment: Вывел, посмотрел. Вы правы. Спасибо Вам. Проблема, действительно, заключалась в другом. Проблема решена.